# How to bring up the iOS multitasking bar in iOS iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, multitasking

I'm trying to test start state of my application when it is "freshly" launched, and when it is launched from a multitasking state.  On an iPad a user can double click on the Home button twice to bring up the multitasking bar, and then you can close all the applications you no longer want running.

This used to be easy, previous versions of the Simulator actually had a home button, but now it doesn't.  In order to go to the home screen you have to go to Simulator -> Hardware -> Home, and there isn't an option listed to simulate a double click of it.

Am I missing something?  Or is there no longer a way to kill applications that are running once they have started in the iPad Simulator without deleting them completely.  I'd be great if I didn't have to push the application each time to my physical iPad every time I make a change to test this part of my application.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you're using the retina iPad simulator you will end up with the home-button-less version.  Go to Hardware->Device->iPad and you'll get a simulator that has a home button you can double click.

You can also use the home button shortcut (default is cmd+shift+h) and double hit that and it will trigger the multitasking bar

Comment: Using Xcode 4.3.3, both the iPad and iPad (Retina) in the Hardware->Devices menu item display an iPad without any home button.  However, the home button shortcut pressed twice works!

Comment: Huh, it is probably as fzwo mentioned, your resolution is possibly too small for it to display the full iPad resolution without hiding the bezel or shrinking the window'

Comment: I'm looking at the simulator on a rather large 1080p monitor, at a scale of 50% it barely takes half of the screen vertically.  Not sure what's going on here...

Comment: Even if you scale it down, it bases whether it will show the bezel on the full size.  With the bezel, I measure the standard iPad simulator as taking up somewhere around 1100 pixels vertically, so that would explain why you don't get the bezel even on the regular iPad simulator.  And for me, when I shrink the regular iPad simulator below 100% it no longer shows the home button/bezel

Comment: MacBook Air with the non-retina iPhone only shows the home button in 100% scaling. At 75% scaling and below it removes the bezel. The retina iPhone 3.5 and 4 inch don't show a bezel at any resolution, and the 100% resolution is larger than the Air's screen. The double-home-button-shortcut worked for me as well. Awesome!

Answer (score 21):

The home button is now hidden from the iPad simulator. However the home button may be triggered by the following command:

```
Apple (command) + Shift + H
```

you should do this command 2 times - just like pressing home button twice.

This will show the multi-task bar

Comment: I guess now in XCode 4.5 , pressing (command)+shift+H  just once will trigger the home button

Comment: Sure it's only hidden from the UI because there's not enough screen space to design a device look like the iPhone non retina for the iPad simulator. MacBooks don't even always have enough space to show the iPad simulators screen. But the functionality is there.

Comment: Any way to do this if I'm on a windows machine, connecting to my mac through VNC?

Comment: Am I the only one who can't ever get this to work, I have to hit it a random number of times but it's never 2 times.

Answer (score 2):

The simulator hides the bezel if it thinks there's not enough room to display it. You can try rotating it, or setting it to a smaller scaling.

But you can also hit the home button via the keyboard shortcut cmd+shift+h; this also works for homebutton double-clicking.

Comment: Even with the device displayed at 50% and in portrait mode, the home button is never shown.  However the cmd+shift+h twice works fine.

Comment: I guess now in XCode 4.5 , pressing (command)+shift+H just once will trigger the home button

Answer (score 1):

use your keyboard to press home button (cmd + shift+h)

to terminate your app drag it up from task bar

Answer (score 0):

Firstly and importantly, you need to **show device bezel**: In `Xcode`, select menu `Window/Show Device Bezel`.

Then it will work like real device: Slide from bottom to show dock, drag the app you want to the right side of opening app.